# Change bootstrap tab body color

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use the following bootstrap code for tabs. 
How can I possibly change the body color for each tab's contents? not the tab itself, but the content associated with it.

Thank you

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Link1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Link2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-4">Link3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the CSS background-color property
`.tab-content { background-color: red }`